# calculating $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{(x^2+y)^n}dx$

Tags: improper-integrals

I would like to know if I solved this improper integral right:

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{(x^2+y)^n}dx$$

for $y\gt 0$

My solution:

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{(x^2+y)^n} \, dx=\lim_{M\rightarrow \infty}\int_0^M1\cdot\frac{1}{(x^2+y)^n} \, dx$$

now I used integration by parts:

$$\left[ \frac{x}{(x^2+y)^n} \right]_0^M-\int_0^M\frac{-2nx}{(x^2+y)^{n+1}} \, dx$$

what is inside the square brackets is $0$ so we get that the integral is:

$$\left[-\frac{1}{(x^2+y)^n}\right]_0^M=\frac 1 {y^n}$$

I'm not sure I could use integration by parts so that's is my main concern.

If I made a mistake please let me now.

edit: I know I made a mistake, what it the right way to solve?

Comment: You know that $\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{x^2+1} = \frac{\pi}{2}$ ...right?  So follow this in your steps to find your mistake.

Comment: You can factor out the variable $y$ after some substitution. Leaving you with some form of a beta integral.

Comment: The mistake in your derivation comes from your integration by parts. If $dv = dx/(x^2+y)^n$, then what is $v$? It's the same problem as you started with, so you haven't accomplished anything.

Comment: @eyeballfrog thank you, I won't do math at 4AM again.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/453783/show-that-int-infty-infty-fracdxx21n1-frac-2n-pi2/453812#453812

Comment: Note that using $x =  \sqrt{y} \,t$ we get 

$$y^{\frac{1}{2}-n}\int^\infty_0 \frac{dt}{(1+t^2)^{n}}$$

Answer (score 0):

By my [essay](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4287506/732917), putting $a=y$ yields the result $$
\boxed{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{d x}{\left(x^{2}+y\right)^{n+1}}=\frac{(2n-1)!!\pi}{2^{n} n !}y^{-\frac{2 n+1}{2}}}
$$